# ASP.NET-C#: Inserting const into TextBox in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have some problems inserting a const "1" into a textbox which is gridview.

The gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableViewState="False">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-CssClass="price" >

<ItemStyle CssClass="price"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>

                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Summary">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Summary") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="picPath">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPic" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("picPath") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="lblquantity" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Total">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

All the information is populated from the session of the previous page, beside this textbox which doesn't comes from anywhere, it's a quantity textbox which the user should enter. And I want it to have a default value of "1".

I don't actually know how to insert into a textbox which is in the gridview.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "quantity">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="lblquantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("quantity") == DBNull.Value ? "1" : Eval("quantity").ToString()' ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

if quantity value is null in the table, then Text property will be default 1. Otherwise it will be quantity column in the table.

Comment: I dont have any original data. I just need to asign 1. how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This may be because code is also checking for Header and footer template..

just put a null check before settings value...

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("lblquantity");
if(tb!=null)
    tb.Text = Convert.ToString(123);
```

This will surely work...

Answer (score 1):

You can put chis code in your GridView's RowDataBound event...

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("lblquantity");
tb.Text = Convert.ToString(123);
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: I get this error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.